# How to give a downloaded file unique name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# application which saves a completed PDF file on a folder inside my site. During the operation I save two session variable to the filename and the filepath in the server:

```
string strFileName = "completed_pdf_" + k + ".pdf"; //k is a variable in a function for the name
Session["fileName"] = strFileName;
MessageBox.Show(Session["fileName"].toString()); //displays: completed_pdf_{name}.pdf

newFileServer = System.Environment.MachineName + @"/PDFGenerate/completed_pdf_" + k + ".pdf";
strFullPath = Path.GetFullPath("//" + newFileServer);
List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem> files = new List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>();
files.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(strFullPath, strFullPath));
strN = files[0].ToString();
Session["pathName"] = strN;
MessageBox.Show(Session["pathName"].toString()); //displays: \\myserver\pdfgen\completed_pdf_{name}.pdf
```

I have a `GridView` which displays a `LinkButton`:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile" />
```

The function for the `LinkButton` is:

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(Session["pathName"].ToString()); //displays correctly
        //MessageBox.Show(Session["fileName"].ToString()); //displays correctly
        Response.Redirect("DownloadFilePDF.ashx?myvar=" + Session["pathName"].ToString() + "&myvar2=" + Session["fileName"].ToString());
    }
```

My `HTTPHandler` code is this:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="DownloadFilePDF" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class DownloadFilePDF : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        System.Web.HttpRequest request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        string strSessVar = request.QueryString["pathName"];

        System.Web.HttpRequest request2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        string strSessVar2 = request.QueryString["fileName"];

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strSessVar + ";");
        response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my website in the server itself, it asks me to download the ASHX file but if I run my website from my local PC which is on the same network as the server, it prompts me to download the PDF file. Everything is good so far, however, I am running into two issues:

1. The filename that is it downloading in my PC is `DownloadFilePDF` which is the HttpHandler filename.
2. The file is 0 Byte and when I open the file, it is not the right file type.

How can I fix so that..

1. The filename is the `fileName` QueryString I am sending to the `HttpHandler` file.
2. I can download the file which is residing in the server itself, so it's not 0 Byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to give a downloaded file unique name

You can use couple of options, like the `Guid` class, `DateTime.Now` method and so on in order to have a unique identifier for the downloaded file, for example, use `Guid.NewGuid`:

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + string.format(strSessVar+{0}, Gui.NewGuid()) + ";");
```

**UPDATE:**

By using the following code you're doing nothing but sending an empty file:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strSessVar + ";");
response.End();
```

In order to solve it, jst stream your file content to the response, look:

```
response.BinaryWrite(GetFileContentsFromSomewhere());
```

Comment: Your example is what I have right now... I would like the file downloaded keep the same filename as it is on the server (if possible).

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge You're simply don't send any file from your server! Look at my update.

Comment: Actually the files are being saved on the server's C:\ drive which I shared with everyone. So in the server, the file is at C:\PDFFolder\{filename}.pdf and from outside of the server I would access it as \\myserver\PDFFolder\{filename}.pdf. How can I fix my code to use that?

Answer (score 1):

Something is amiss here.  I don't see any content being streamed to the client.  You need to provide the content in the response, like this:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strSessVar + ";");
response.BinaryWrite(GetFileContentsFromSomewhere());  //<--- this baby does all the magic
response.End();
```

The GetFileContentsFromSomewhere() implementation depends on where you intend the file to come from.  If it's just a static file on your web server, you could use something like this:

```
response.WriteFile(localPathOfFile);
```

or

```
response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(urlOfFile));
```

Comment: What should be inside the baby? :/

Comment: Where is your file coming from?